# How to know if two or more events are equally likely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $S$ be a sample space associated with an experiment . Two events $E_i,E_j \in S$ are equally likely events if :

$$P(E_i)=P(E_j)$$

If we need to prove above, we find the probabilities of $E_i,E_j$ and show that they are equal. But to find the probabilities of $E_i,E_j$, we need to use the formula :

$$P(E)= \frac{\mathrm {n(favourable)}}{\mathrm{n(Total)}}$$

Further, this formula is not true in general. It's only true if the events in $S$ are equally likely.

So , isn't all of this just circular as we are checking if events are likely or not on the basis of a formula which itself is only true for equally likely events? How to know exactly know if some events are equally likely or not in a rigorous way?

I'm very bad at probability and this question is boggling me from many days.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, this is not a math question. If a perticular die is fair cannot be decided by mathematics, it's a physics question, for example. The probability of a newborn baby being male or female is a question of biology (and the distribution is only roughly, but not exactly, 50:50).

In math, we generally make assumptions that are unfortunately not often completely stated. So in theory, if you are given a sample space and asked to calculate probability of events (which are subsets of the sample space), you cannot do anything unless you already know the probability of each atomic event (= element of the sample space).

In practice, you have to  make assumptions about things having equal probability. What are reasonable assumptions and what are not are then again question of experience and non-mathematical knowledge.

Comment: So does this means that probability theory is based on assumptions , experiences and beliefs rather than a concrete mathematical basis ?

Comment: No. The mathematical part is based on measure theory. But what measure you apply to your sample space is more or less arbitrary mathematically. What a reasonably measure is when you are solving practical problems is a mixture between mathematics ("What exactly is a measure?" is a mathematical question) and real-world knowledge ("That die is fair, so we assume that $p(1)=p(2)=\ldots=p(6) =1/6$).

I don't know how far into your probability learning you are, so "measure" may not make sense to you yet. But again, there is no a priori **mathematical reason** for a die to be fair.

Comment: I think I got the answer. Mathematics is made by humans.

Answer (score 2):

$P(E_i) = P(E_j)$ is just another way of saying $E_i$ and $E_j$ are equally likely events. These are not two distinct statements, with one implying the other.

You are right about the formula below. It does presuppose the condition that all events in the sample space are equally likely.

$$P(E) = \frac{n(E)}{n(S)}$$

So yes, we can't use this formula to prove $P(E_i) = P(E_j)$.

Now, consider the example of rolling a fair die. When we say the probabilities of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 showing up are all equal, it's not because of any formula. Rather it results from our assumption that the die is "fair". It results from the symmetry of the die that makes the events indistinguishable from one another (except for the labels on the faces).

Next, consider this.

We roll a fair die twice and take the sum of the numbers showing up. Also $E_n$ represents the event with the sum being $n$.

Now, the probability of the sum being 2 is the same as the probability of it being 12.

$$P(E_2) = P(E_{12})$$

How do we know/prove this?

We **DON'T** say the sum can be anything from 2 to 12, so a total of 11 events. That means $P(E_2) = 1/11$ and $P(E_{12}) = 1/11$. So, $P(E_2)$ and $P(E_{12})$ are equally likely.

We can't do this because we don't know that all the events ($E_{2}$ to $E_{12}$) have the same likelihood.

Besides, if we did so, we'd be using circular reasoning. Assuming all the events are equally likely to prove that two of the events are equally likely.

Instead, here's how we can prove it.

For the sum to be 2, we must get 1 on each roll. The probability of the happening is $1/6 \times 1/6 = 1/36$.

And for the sum to be 12, we must get 6 on each roll. The probability of that would also be $1/6 \times 1/6 = 1/36$.

The two probabilities turn out to be equal. In other words, the two events are equally likely. See? No circular reasoning this time.

Comment: The argument of symmetry or otherwise methods can be applied intuitively to simple examples of coins and dice like you did. But what about problems involving more complex experiments ? Doesn't it just shows that the whole of probability theory is based on assumptions , experiences and beliefs rather than a concrete mathematical basis ?

Comment: In more complex experiments you again make mathematical assumptions, based on real world experience, that turn out to model the real world very well. That in the real world sometimes forumalting the relationships between different parts of the "experiment" is very hard is certainly true. See for example this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_Clark where a woman was convicted of killing her kids based on incorrect assumptions how certain real world events where relared.

Comment: @Ingix Thank you for your comment. I think it adresses OP's comment.

I would just add that in this context, our need to for assumptions are more a reflection of the real world and its complexity than any shortcomings in the mathematical theory.